# 5GHz wifi networks not showing on Ubuntu 22.04 (mt7921e)

Tags: wireless, 22.04, msi

Setup:
Dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Windows 10.
Motherboard: MSI B550M PRO-VDH WiFi

The motherboard has an inbuilt wifi module and they specify the following on the producer's website:

- *Supports Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac, dual band (2.4GHz, 5GHz) up to 433 Mbps speed.*
- *LAN Realtek® RTL8111HN Gigabit LAN*
- *Wi-Fi / Bluetooth Wi-Fi AC, Bluetooth 4.2*

The wifi module works as intended on Windows 10, connecting to a 5GHz network without issues.
On Ubuntu I have observed that the 5GHz network appears very rarely (I switch between windows and linux frequently), most of the time connecting only to my 2.4GHz network. Most of the time can't see, nor connect to 5GHz networks.

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp42s0   no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"IP a lot"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: AC:15:A2:AE:77:63   
          Bit Rate=172 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

**iwlist wlo1 freq**

```
wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: MEDIATEK Corp.
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:29:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 00
   serial: bc:f4:d4:3f:d9:43
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless fb
   configuration: broadcast=yes depth=32 driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.7.1-060701-generic firmware=____000000-20221227123243 ip=192.168.0.177 latency=0 link=yes mode=2560x1440 multicast=yes visual=truecolor wireless=IEEE 802.11 xres=2560 yres=1440
   resources: iomemory:7e0-7df irq:73 memory:7e10100000-7e101fffff memory:fcd00000-fcd07fff

   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:2a:00.0
   logical name: enp42s0
   version: 15
   serial: 04:7c:16:83:48:78
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.7.1-060701-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:36 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcc04000-fcc04fff memory:fcc00000-fcc03fff
```

**lspci**

```
...
29:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616
2a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
...
```

I tried upgrading the kernel to the latest release with current being

**uname -r**

```
6.7.1-060701-generic
```

I have disabled

- Windows Fast Startup
- Sleep
- Hybernate
- Secure Boot in BIOS

However I still suspect that there is some interference between the two operating systems.

**Edit 1**

@chili555
**nmcli device wifi list**

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID          MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS SECURITY  
*       AC:15:A2:AE:77:63  IP a lot      Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  61      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
    84:D8:1B:2D:86:7C  TP-Link_867C  Infra  5     195 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
    78:57:73:E4:9B:B0  A1_9BA7       Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2      
    60:E3:27:A0:2D:F2  Miroslava     Infra  9     270 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2      
    60:32:B1:DD:86:D6  Hristina      Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2      
    AC:15:A2:8E:D2:8C  TP-Link_D28D  Infra  10    270 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

**Edit 2**

**sudo iwlist scan**

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp42s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      Failed to read scan data : Resource temporarily unavailable

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

**edit 3**

**iw phy | grep 'MHz ['**

```
* 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
* 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
* 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
* 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
* 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
* 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
* 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
* 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
* 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
* 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
* 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
* 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5720 MHz [144] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
* 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
* 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
* 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
* 5955 MHz [1] (disabled)
* 5975 MHz [5] (disabled)
* 5995 MHz [9] (disabled)
* 6015 MHz [13] (disabled)
* 6035 MHz [17] (disabled)
* 6055 MHz [21] (disabled)
* 6075 MHz [25] (disabled)
* 6095 MHz [29] (disabled)
* 6115 MHz [33] (disabled)
* 6135 MHz [37] (disabled)
* 6155 MHz [41] (disabled)
* 6175 MHz [45] (disabled)
* 6195 MHz [49] (disabled)
* 6215 MHz [53] (disabled)
* 6235 MHz [57] (disabled)
* 6255 MHz [61] (disabled)
* 6275 MHz [65] (disabled)
* 6295 MHz [69] (disabled)
* 6315 MHz [73] (disabled)
* 6335 MHz [77] (disabled)
* 6355 MHz [81] (disabled)
* 6375 MHz [85] (disabled)
* 6395 MHz [89] (disabled)
* 6415 MHz [93] (disabled)
* 6435 MHz [97] (disabled)
* 6455 MHz [101] (disabled)
* 6475 MHz [105] (disabled)
* 6495 MHz [109] (disabled)
* 6515 MHz [113] (disabled)
* 6535 MHz [117] (disabled)
* 6555 MHz [121] (disabled)
* 6575 MHz [125] (disabled)
* 6595 MHz [129] (disabled)
* 6615 MHz [133] (disabled)
* 6635 MHz [137] (disabled)
* 6655 MHz [141] (disabled)
* 6675 MHz [145] (disabled)
* 6695 MHz [149] (disabled)
* 6715 MHz [153] (disabled)
* 6735 MHz [157] (disabled)
* 6755 MHz [161] (disabled)
* 6775 MHz [165] (disabled)
* 6795 MHz [169] (disabled)
* 6815 MHz [173] (disabled)
* 6835 MHz [177] (disabled)
* 6855 MHz [181] (disabled)
* 6875 MHz [185] (disabled)
* 6895 MHz [189] (disabled)
* 6915 MHz [193] (disabled)
* 6935 MHz [197] (disabled)
* 6955 MHz [201] (disabled)
* 6975 MHz [205] (disabled)
* 6995 MHz [209] (disabled)
* 7015 MHz [213] (disabled)
* 7035 MHz [217] (disabled)
* 7055 MHz [221] (disabled)
* 7075 MHz [225] (disabled)
* 7095 MHz [229] (disabled)
* 7115 MHz [233] (disabled)
```

Comment: Do the 5Ghz networks appear in `sudo iwlist scan`?

Comment: Please show us: `nmcli device wifi list' Only include any instances of your SSID, *IP a lot*.

Comment: @DanielT Edited post to add the results.

Comment: @chili555 Edited post to add the results.

Comment: @PavelNedelchev What about `iw phy | grep 'MHz \['`?

Comment: It appears to be a known issue. https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/3106 I'm studying. "I tried upgrading the kernel to the latest" What is the oldest kernel on your system? `ls /boot` It appears that the issue is only present in kernel versions 6.2 and later.

Comment: @chili555 nice find! My oldest kernel appears to be /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic
Are you suggesting to downgrade the kernel ? Would it be a sustainable solution to downgrade from 6.7.x to 6.1.x ? I'm worried it may lead to other issues

Comment: As far as I can find, the firmware downgrade has problems and the kernel downgrade, as far as Google and I can find, have none. I suggest you try it. It can be easily reverted if it's troublesome. https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.1.74/